# В обработчик php уходит [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Пытаюсь передать сгенерированный QR код в PNG на сервер под заданным идентификатором, используя FormData, но судя по var_dump в обработчик попадает [object Promise].

Вот код, который генерит изображение через библиотеку QR Code Styling и передает через ajax в обработчик:

```
    const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
        width: 490,
        height: 490,
        type: "canvas",
        data: "https://www.vk.com/",
        image: "./img/gvoice_i.png",
        dotsOptions: {
            color: "#fff",
            type: "rounded"
        },
        
        cornersSquareOptions: {
            type: "extra-rounded"
        },
        
        backgroundOptions: {
            color: "transparent"},

        imageOptions: {
            imageSize: 0.5,
            saveAsBlob: true,
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            margin: 5
        }
    });

var pngBlob  = qrCode.getRawData('png');

var myformData = new FormData();        
myformData.append('QRcode', pngBlob);
myformData.append('FileName', 'Filename');

    $.ajax('ajax.php',{
        method: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: myformData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
    });
```

Обработчик PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['FileName'].".png";
$png = $_POST['QRcode'];
$myfile = fopen($name, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $png);
?>
```

Var_dump:

```
array(2) {
  ["QRcode"]=>
  string(16) "[object Promise]"
  ["FileName"]=>
  string(8) "Filename"
}
```

Comment: Судя по ответу, картинка не успевает сгенерироваться и возвращает промис на свое место. Поэтому и отправляется на сервер [object Promise]. Попробуйте, добавить через конструкцию Promise.then()

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
qrCode.getRawData('png').then(qrImg => {
  var myformData = new FormData();        
  myformData.append('QRcode', qrImg );
  myformData.append('FileName', 'Filename');

  $.ajax('ajax.php',{
    method: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    data: myformData,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
});
});
```

Comment: попробовал, создается пустой файл(( по var_dump только filename передает: array(1) { ["FileName"] => string(8) "Filename" }